# using @InjectMocks outside @Before

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm creating the base for my unit testing project( Spring boot rest controller) and I'm having a problem passing @InjectMocks value because it's only evaluated in @Before and therefore a nullpointer is thrown when i try to access it outside

Some tips to get around the problem please?
Thank you very much

Ps : Any other advices on best practices or something i did wrong for unit testing regarding my current base class test will be appreciated as well

Class to test (rest controller)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/management")
@Api(description = "Users count connections", produces = "application/json", tags = {"ConnectionManagement API"})
public class ConnectionManagementControllerImpl implements ConnectionManagementController {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionManagementBusinessService connectionManagementBusinessService;

    @Override
    @PostMapping(value = "/countConnectionsByInterval" , consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "count all users connections by interval")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ConnectionsCountDto>> countConnectionsByInterval(@RequestBody String format) {
        List<ConnectionsCountDto> connectionManagement = connectionManagementBusinessService.countConnectionsByInterval(format);
        return  new ResponseEntity<List<ConnectionsCountDto>>(connectionManagement, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Abstract base test

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseTest<C> {

     public MockMvc mockMvc;

     private Class<C> clazz;

     private Object inject;

     protected abstract String getURL();

     protected final void setTestClass(final Class<C> classToSet, final Object injectToSet) {
         clazz = Preconditions.checkNotNull(classToSet);
         inject = Preconditions.checkNotNull(injectToSet);
     }

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(clazz);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(inject).build();
    }

    protected MockHttpServletResponse getResponse(MediaType produces) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                get(getURL()).
                accept(produces)).
                andReturn().
                getResponse();
        return response;
    }

    protected MockHttpServletResponse postResponse(String content , MediaType consumes , MediaType produces) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                post(getURL()).
                content(content).
                contentType(consumes).
                accept(produces)).
                andReturn().
                getResponse();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest extends AbstractBaseTest<ConnectionManagementControllerImpl>{

    @Mock
    private ConnectionManagementBusinessService connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConnectionManagementControllerImpl connectionManagementControllerMocked;

    public ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest() {
        super();            
        setTestClass(ConnectionManagementControllerImpl.class , connectionManagementControllerMocked); // null pointer there
    }

    @Test
    public void countConnectionsByInterval() throws Exception {

        // given
        given(connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked.countConnectionsByInterval(Mockito.anyString()))
                .willReturn(new ArrayList<ConnectionsCountDto>());

        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = postResponse("day" , MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        // then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());    
    }

    @Override
    protected String getURL() {
        return "/management/countConnectionsByInterval";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as intended. However, you can setup mocks manually and inject them inside `ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest` constructor (before calling `setTestClass(...)`):

```
public ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest() {
    super();

    connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked = Mockito.mock(ConnectionManagementBusinessService.class);

    connectionManagementControllerMocked = new ConnectionManagementControllerImpl();
    connectionManagementControllerMocked.setConnectionManagementBusinessService(connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked);

    setTestClass(ConnectionManagementControllerImpl.class, connectionManagementControllerMocked);
}
```

Do not forget to remove `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations. Btw you can even remove `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` in that case.

**UPDATE:** Both the constructor of test class and "init" method annotated with `@Before` are executed for each test. The difference is that Mockito annotations are processed between constructor and `@Before` method invocations.

So you can slightly change your code in order to achieve a positive result:

1. Create "init" method (annotated with `@Before`) inside `ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest` and move `setTestClass()` into it from the constructor (in that particular case you can also remove the whole constructor because it would contain only `super()` invocation).
2. Add `super.init()` after `setTestClass()` line (otherwise "init" method in the parent class will be ignored by JUnit).
3. (Optional) you could also remove `@Before` annotation from the "init" method in the parent class if your tests are written in the same manner.

The example of code refactored in that way:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseTest<C> {

    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    private Class<C> clazz;

    private Object inject;

    protected abstract String getURL();

    protected final void setTestClass(final Class<C> classToSet, final Object injectToSet) {
        clazz = Preconditions.checkNotNull(classToSet);
        inject = Preconditions.checkNotNull(injectToSet);
    }

    @Before //this annotation can be removed
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(clazz); //this line also can be removed because MockitoJUnitRunner does it for you
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(inject).build();
    }

    protected MockHttpServletResponse getResponse(MediaType produces) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                get(getURL()).
                        accept(produces)).
                andReturn().
                getResponse();
        return response;
    }

    protected MockHttpServletResponse postResponse(String content , MediaType consumes , MediaType produces) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                post(getURL()).
                        content(content).
                        contentType(consumes).
                        accept(produces)).
                andReturn().
                getResponse();
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest extends AbstractBaseTest<ConnectionManagementControllerImpl> {

    @Mock
    private ConnectionManagementBusinessService connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConnectionManagementControllerImpl connectionManagementControllerMocked;

    //constructor can be removed
    public ConnectionManagementControllerImplTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        setTestClass(ConnectionManagementControllerImpl.class, connectionManagementControllerMocked);
        super.init();
    }

    @Test
    public void countConnectionsByInterval() throws Exception {

        // given
        given(connectionManagementBusinessServiceMocked.countConnectionsByInterval(Mockito.anyString()))
                .willReturn(new ArrayList<ConnectionsCountDto>());

        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = postResponse("day", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        // then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getURL() {
        return "/management/countConnectionsByInterval";
    }
}
```

P.S. I'd prefer the former approach, but if you don't want to have a setter for `ConnectionManagementBusinessService`, you can choose the latter. I've tested both of them and the result was the same.

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer but i cannot use it because otherwise , i must put setter on all my controller which i don t want because i am using Spring autowired mechanism.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the way of how to do it with the field injection of ConnectionManagementBusinessService, but (as a little off-topic if you don't mind) why do you prefer it to the setter and/or constructor injection? Spring's team recommends to use the latter ([they even dropped the section about field injection from the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators)). The good article about it: https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/

Comment: thank you very much , working like a charm. moreover the links you provided are very interesting . i never used constructor injection because field injection do the job but it's way better because it can be used in non cdi environment (like unit test justly). this is clearly the best practice so i will change all my controller to constructor injection. you have my gratitude :)